# How to get logged user's information in drawer menu?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, navigation-drawer

I've tried to retrieve the current user's username and email from firebase and display it in the drawer menu. However, the program crashed and return the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.myapplication.NavigationActivity$1.onDataChange(NavigationActivity.java:79)
```

Here is my Navigation Activity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    protected DrawerLayout drawer;
    private String userId;
    private TextView email,name;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userId= mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        getUserInformation();

    }

    private void getUserInformation() {
        DatabaseReference userDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

        userDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (child.getKey().equals("name")) {//find the child that Equals to start
                            name.setText(child.getValue().toString());
                        }
                        if (child.getKey().equals("email")) {//find the child that Equals to start
                            email.setText(child.getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_run:
                Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this,running_map.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_history:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this,HistoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                finish();
                break;
            //......
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my database:
[image]
I guessed that this is because the NavigationActivity was not the main activity, however, even when I changed it to the main activity, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need the for loop:

```
    private void getUserInformation() {
        DatabaseReference userDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

        userDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class).equals("name")) {//find the child that Equals to start
                            name.setText(child.getValue().toString());
                        }
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class).equals("email")) {//find the child that Equals to start
                            email.setText(child.getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Your reference is at node `userId`, therefore to get the details you dont need to iterate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realised the error about the for loop after reading your code but the program still returned the same error. I think the problem is where I tried to get userId using ```mAuth``` , as when I deleted the ```getUserInformation``` function and added ```name.setText(userId)``` , the same error occur.

Comment: Do u have id name in the xml?

Comment: In your navigationview tag in xml, you probably have `app:headerLayout="@layout/my_nav_layout`, then in the java code you need to access the TextView that is inside `my_nav_layout` so you can do the folllowing: `name =(TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.name);` the error is because the TextView does not exist...but you also had a problem with the data retrieved